# Are classes allowed to have different definitions across different translation units in a program?

Tags: c++, linkage, one-definition-rule

Is it well-formed to define a class differently in different translation units granted that the class is defined at most once in each translation unit?

Use case is accessing implementation details without dynamic allocation. C++ code will operate on pointers already allocated by a C library.

Please ignore memory leaks for the sake of example.

common.hpp

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace Test {

class Impl;

class A {
    void *ptr;
    A(void *ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    friend class Impl;

   public:
    int plus_one();
};

class B {
    void *ptr;
    B(void *ptr) : ptr(ptr) {}
    friend class Impl;

   public:
    int plus_two();
};

class Factory {
   public:
    A getA(int val);
    B getB(int val);
};

}  // namespace Test
```

A.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.hpp"

namespace Test {

class Impl {
   public:
    static int as_int(A *a) { return *static_cast<int *>(a->ptr) + 1; }
};

int A::plus_one() { return Impl{}.as_int(this); }

}  // namespace Test
```

B.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.hpp"

namespace Test {

class Impl {
   public:
    static int as_int(B *b) { return *static_cast<int *>(b->ptr) + 2; }
};

int B::plus_two() { return Impl{}.as_int(this); }

}  // namespace Test
```

Factory.cpp

```cpp
#include "common.hpp"

namespace Test {

class Impl {
   public:
    static A getA(int val) { return A(new int{val}); }
    static B getB(int val) { return B(new int{val}); }
};

A Factory::getA(int val) { return Impl{}.getA(val); }
B Factory::getB(int val) { return Impl{}.getB(val); }

}  // namespace Test
```

main.cpp

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "common.hpp"

int main() {
    Test::Factory factory;
    std::cout << factory.getA(1).plus_one() << std::endl;
    std::cout << factory.getB(1).plus_two() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ A.cpp B.cpp Factory.cpp main.cpp -o test 
$ ./test
2
3
```

Comment: These various `Impl` seem to be unrelated—why not just forward-declare several friend types?

Comment: @DavisHerring It's been a while. I don't exactly remember details of the use case but later I solved it by submitting a patch upstream for guarding their C headers with `extern "C"` so I didn't have to go through these ugly hacks or redeclaring everything redundantly in the ported library. (But frankly curiosity was more motivating for this question.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the same class type is not allowed to have different definitions. Your program is in a direct violation of the ODR, and exhibits undefined behavior.

> **[basic.def.odr]**
>
> [6](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.def.odr#6) There can be more than one definition of a class type, [...] in
>   a program provided that each definition appears in a different
>   translation unit, and provided the definitions satisfy the following
>   requirements. Given such an entity named D defined in more than one
>   translation unit, then
>
> - each definition of D shall consist of the same sequence of tokens; and
> - [...]
>
> [...] If the definitions of D satisfy all these requirements, then the
>   behavior is as if there were a single definition of D. If the
>   definitions of D do not satisfy these requirements, then the behavior
>   is undefined.

Your two definitions quite obviously differ in their token sequences already, and so the conditions of the ODR are not upheld.